# Roslyn Vsix stopped working after moving the project

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I had a working Roslyn VSIX Project for analyzing resources that could be localizable.  Everything was working fine until I moved the project to a new location.

The analyzer's still seem to run and trigger the Code fix, However, the Code Action is never Registered into visual studio, so there is no option for that fix for some reason.

My analyzer:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class ConstDiagnosticAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "Viventium.Localization.Tools.ConstantToResource";

    // You can change these strings in the Resources.resx file. If you do not want your analyzer to be localize-able, you can use regular strings for Title and MessageFormat.
    // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Localizing%20Analyzers.md for more on localization
    private static readonly LocalizableString Title = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.ConstAnalyzerTitle), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.ConstAnalyzerMessageFormat), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private static readonly LocalizableString Description = new LocalizableResourceString(nameof(Resources.ConstAnalyzerDescription), Resources.ResourceManager, typeof(Resources));
    private const string Category = "Naming";

    private static ResourceLocalizationRule localizationRule = new ResourceLocalizationRule();

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeConstDeclaration, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);
    }

    public static void AnalyzeConstDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var fieldDeclaration = (FieldDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

        if (false == IsValidConstDeclaration(context, fieldDeclaration))
        {
            return;
        }

        var firstVariable = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();
        var firstSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstVariable);

        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), firstSymbol.Name));
    }

    private static bool VariableIsInResx(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclaration)
    {
        var solution = context.GetSolution();
        var documentPropertyMap = PropertyMapCache.GetDocumentPropertyMap(solution);

        return localizationRule.IsFieldDeclaredInResx(fieldDeclaration, documentPropertyMap);
    }

    private static bool IsValidConstDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax fieldDeclaration)
    {
        if (false == fieldDeclaration.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.Count > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var declaredVariable = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();

        var initializer = declaredVariable.Initializer;
        if (initializer == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var constantValue = context.SemanticModel.GetConstantValue(initializer.Value);
        if (!constantValue.HasValue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var variableTypeName = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Type;
        var variableType = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variableTypeName).ConvertedType;

        if (variableType.SpecialType != SpecialType.System_String)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The Fix Provider:

```
[ExportCodeFixProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof(ConstantToResourceCodeFixProvider)), Shared]
public class ConstantToResourceCodeFixProvider : CodeFixProvider
{
    #region Consts

    private const string title = "Convert Constant Use Resources";

    #endregion

    #region CodeFixProvider Overrides

    public sealed override ImmutableArray<string> FixableDiagnosticIds
    {
        get { return ImmutableArray.Create(ConstDiagnosticAnalyzer.DiagnosticId); }
    }

    public sealed override FixAllProvider GetFixAllProvider()
    {
        // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/FixAllProvider.md for more information on Fix All Providers
        return WellKnownFixAllProviders.BatchFixer;
    }

    public sealed override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // TODO: Replace the following code with your own analysis, generating a CodeAction for each fix to suggest
        var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
        var diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;

        // Find the type declaration identified by the diagnostic.
        var declaration = root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        // Register a code action that will invoke the fix.
        context.RegisterCodeFix(
            CodeActionWithPreview.CreateStateful(
                title: title,
                createChangedDocument: (c, isPreview) => this.CheckConstForLocalization(context, declaration, isPreview, c),
                equivalenceKey: title),
            diagnostic);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Analyzer Logic

    private async Task<Document> CheckConstForLocalization(CodeFixContext context, FieldDeclarationSyntax field, bool isPreview, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var documentPropertyMap = PropertyMapCache.GetDocumentPropertyMap(context.Document.Project.Solution);

        var localizationRule = new ResourceLocalizationRule();
        var updatedDocument = localizationRule.ConvertDocumentToUseResources(context.Document, documentPropertyMap, field, isPreview, cancellationToken);

        return await updatedDocument;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Can some one please give me a hint to of what is going on an how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of debugging it turns out Diagnostic Analyzer's are not allowed to have periods in them...

```
public const string DiagnosticId = "Viventium_Localization_Tools_ConstantToResource";
```

The fix was quite simple I just changed the DiagnosticId to use underscores, and I've opened a bug with [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20213)